# Simple example of Gradient Boosting

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I'm trying to understand gradient boosting (GB) but even though I read a lot of explanations I'm still not sure I understand it correctly. I'll give a simple example of my understanding first. 
Let's say we want to apply GB to the following problem: we want to predict number of inhabitants based on number of rooms. Our 1-dimensional training data is x = [2,5,4,7,1,3] and labels are y = [4,7,4,4,1,1]. Since GB is composed of many models our first model might produce the following mapping:

```
[1] model_1([2,5,4,7,1,3]) => [0,2,4,12,2,4]
```

The input of this model is x, number of rooms, the output is y^, number of inhabitants. This means our residuals are [4,5,0,-8,-1,-3]. My main question is: **What is the input and output of the second model?** 
From what I understand the input is again x, but the output is the residuals, i.e. we are trying to predict the residuals [4,5,0,-8,-1,-3] based on x:

```
[2] model_2([2,5,4,7,1,3]) => [3,2,0,-4,-1,-1]
```

After training model_2 we don't quite get it right but we are closer. We calculate the difference between the residuals [4,5,0,-8,-1,-3] and model_2 predictions and we get [1,3,0,-4,0,-2]. We create model_4 that tries to map x onto [1,3,0,-4,0,-2]:

```
[3]  model_3([2,5,4,7,1,3]) => [1,3,0,-4,0,-3]
```

We got only last sample wrong so we stop iterating and the final GB model looks like this:

```
[4] GB(x) = model_1(x) + model_2(x) + model_3(x)
```

which means that when our new data point is 2 our model will first predict 3, the second model will add 3 and the last model will add 1. This sums up to 7. Looking at our first training data point we also predicted 7 for x=2 so it should be more or less correct.

Is this a correct explanation of how GB works? If not, can you explain what the second model does in terms of the above example?

Comment: There are several implementations of gradient boosting so the input/output details might vary. But this example seems more or less right.

Comment: The difference between ordinary boosting and gradient boosting is that the latter has a loss function that is minimized by the "weak learners". Often the predictions of the weak learners are weighted, and thus each model can be seen as a step into the direction of the gradient of the loss function. Hence, gradient boosting!